# Bash: call array item by string

Tags: bash

How can I access array elements by string?

What I want to achieve is the following: I have a number of json files in a directory. These should be read in one after the other. All key values ​​("id", "test") should be configured / replaced. The changes should be saved in the json files.

```
#a json file example: 
{
  "id": "<fill-id>",
  "test": "<fill-test>"
}
```

The first key "id" should call the function "create_id".
The second key "test" should call the function "create_test".

```
#!/bin/sh

declare -a FUNCTION
FUNCTION["id"]="create_id"
FUNCTION["test"]="create_test"
FUNCTION["secret"]="FUNCTION.C"

# read key/value from json file 
for filename in *.json; do
  while read -r key value; do
    declare "$key=$value"
    echo name: $key value: $value
     ${FUNCTION[$key]} $filename $value
  done < <(jq -r 'to_entries[] | "\(.key) \(.value)"' $filename)
done
```

Comment: jq can read more than one file at a time. So is it actually necessary for you to create the loop in shell code? What would happen if you did `jq -r … *.json`? I wonder if you could write this script as a pretty simple jq that outputs something sh can run, like `jq … *.json | sh`

Comment: @kojiro Do you know the jq call to create an array in bash with all key/value pairs from the json file? So I can read all key-value pairs, update all values of the keys and write the array back to the json file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to use an *associative* array, `declare -A FUNCTION`

***BUT*** associative arrays are not a `sh` feature: `declare -A` is [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) syntax. Change your `#!` line.

You'll also need bash version 4.0 or greater: the default /bin/bash on MacOSX is too old.

You can also find associative arrays in ksh and zsh.

Comment: the process substitution syntax OP is using is also not valid `sh` syntax, so even if they decide not to use associative arrays, they still must use bash.